# How to produce an app bundle so that user can double click to launch docker application?

Tags: docker, app-bundle

Suppose I have a docker application (such as [this one](https://github.com/deddu/nyxt-docker)). The standard usage is using the CLI to run `docker run`, in this case, for **macOS** users it would be:

```sh
docker run -it --rm bigdeddu/nyxt:2.2.1
```

Now, I would like to produce an app bundle or something so that users can double click to launch this docker application as a desktop application. It would be kind of a GUI shortcut to launch docker.

How can I achieve that?

1 - Is there a solution already done for it? If so, which one?

2 - If there is **not** a solution already done for it, what would be a rough sketch on how to build one?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a .desktop file, provide the execute commnad which in this case can be a the shell script you want to run. Double clicking that . desktop file will run your application. For further details, check how to create .desktop file in linux. Dont forget. Provide the path of your script for running docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker was designed to encapsulate server processes. For servers, the CLI is a reasonable and often satisfactory interface.

If you want users to run their possibly interactive application, you may want to look for https://appimage.org/. Although I am unsure whether that is available for MacOS.

To get around these limitations, you could either think of creating an end user targeting GUI for docker, or an implementation of AppImage for MacOS.